# Custom message in Spring AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, error-handling

In my Spring Boot Web application I am throwing a `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException` in my business code whenever a user does not have a necessary authority. The `AccessDeniedException` has the advantage that Spring automatically calls the AuthenticationEntryPoint etc.

However, I am using a custom exception message to indicate the exact cause of the exception (e.g. `throw new AccessDeniedException("You do not have permissions to do XYZ")`, but in the generated JSON response the message is always "Access Denied", e.g.:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-12-12T10:01:10.342+0000",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/myurl"
}
```

Digging into the code of Spring (`DefaultErrorAttributes` method `addErrorDetails`) reveals that the message is built from 1) the exception message 2) the request attribute `javax.servlet.error.message`, with the second overriding the first.

Does anybody know why the request attribute has priority over the exception message?

And is there an easy way to display the custom exception message within the Spring Boot error response? I would like to retain the default Spring Boot error response, but with my custom message in the "message" field and ideally I want Spring Boot to construct the rest of the JSON object (i.e. timestamp, status, etc). The final result should look something like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-12-12T10:01:10.342+0000",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "You do not have permissions to do XYZ",
  "path": "/myurl"
}
```

This does work for other kinds of exceptions. Just AccessDeniedException seems to be a special case. Is AccessDeniedException maybe not the right choice for this rqeuirement (although the javadoc suggests it is)?

Comment: *However, I am using a custom exception message to indicate the exact cause of the exceptionHowever, I am using a custom exception message to indicate the exact cause of the exception*. How are you doing that? Isn't that relevant to your question.

Comment: Simply by passing my message in the constructor. Thanks for pointing it out, I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Springs [ControllerAdvice](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice) and send a custom error using the `HttpServletResponse`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class AccessDeniedExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public void handleConflict(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(403, "Your Message");
    }
}
```

This will return:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1576248996366,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Your Message",
  "path": "/foo/bar"
}
```

This way you can globally catch all Exceptions of a specific type and make your controller return a specified custom value. You could do so as well e.g. for any `IOException` and return a 404 Not Found `ResponseEntity` with a message you specify.

Comment: I am aware of the different methods to produce different error results based on the exception. However, with this method I see the same problem as with Ashok Kumar N original answer: It only returns a single String instead of a JSON object looking like the default Spring Boot error response. The reason why I specifically asked to change "message" field of the Spring Boot to do as much of the work as possible.

Comment: @terminal my bad, got it. I edited my answer, this should work out for your use case now.

Comment: thanks, this does exactly what I want in just a few lines of code!

Answer (score 3):

> place the method inside the implementation class
>   **AccessDeniedHandlerImpl with AccessDeniedHandler interface**

```
    @Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                   AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.add("timestamp", Instant.now().toString());
    jsonObject.add("status", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
    jsonObject.add("error", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.getReasonPhrase());
    jsonObject.add("message","********* custom message what you want ********");
    jsonObject.add("path", request.getRequestURI());

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
    response.getWriter().write( mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObject));
}
```

try this if you have a security configuration like below and

> add the **AccessDeniedHandlerImpl as default accessDeniedHandler**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                AccessDeniedHandler defaultAccessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
                defaultAccessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException); // handle the custom acessDenied class here
            });
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER"))
            .withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN"));
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am afraid my question wasn't quite clear. I would like to retain the Spring Boot error response JSON, just with my custom message. I think your approach returns only the message if I am not mistaken. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @terminal I updated the answer based on the comments

Comment: your answer is certainly a solution, although not a very elegant one because it requires me to duplicate a lot of what the Spring Boot ErrorAttributes already do. I was actually looking for a way to make the DefaultErrorAttributes produce the result I want. I am sorry my question still wasn't clear enough. I refined it again.

Comment: Then you can follow the @ Alan Hay comment its more easier

Comment: which comment do you mean? Alan Hay just asked how I am using a custom message